# How do I identify all the display objects in the display list in ActionScript, below the one that I have clicked?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do I identify all the display objects in the display list in ActionScript, below the one that I have clicked? All the other objects are shadowed by the first one. 
What if other objects have visible parameter as hidden?

Chris

Comment: Do you want it to check recursively? What do you mean by identify?

Comment: As I said I want to know what objects are hidden under the visible one which is above the others so I can't identify them (ie. find their ids).

Comment: Can I ask why you need this?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this:

If you want to know all the objects under a point you could do this:
[Actionscript 3: get display object at pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747709/actionscript-3-get-display-object-at-pixel)

```
var myObjects: Array = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(5, 5));
```

replace 'stage' with any display object as well.

You can also cycle though every diplayobject and do a hit test with another display object (with a index lower than it)

Comment: It works nicely but it will not detect objects with visibility = false

Comment: you could go alpha = 0, of course keep an eye on performance when you mess with the alpha.